# What is the fastest way to produce a reproducible random sample in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an Amazon Redshift table with almost a billion rows and want to sample 100000 of them at random.  I've tried a query almost identical to

```
select BrowserId, 
from PageViews pv
group by BrowserId
order by md5('seed' || BrowserId)
limit 100000;
```

as described [here](http://blog.data-miners.com/2014/02/taking-random-sample-on-amazon-redshift.html), but it is taking two or more hours to run because the sort operation dominates the pull.

Comment: I'm running it on the equivalent of the PageViews table in its own schema via the command line.

Comment: Here are some suggestions for other DBs check them if they might help youhttps://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster.html

Comment: I saw this and it doesn't work because Redshift doesn't support generate_series().  Additionally, optimizing Redshift is different from optimizing other databases because Redshift is column-based and standard SQL databases are row-based.

Comment: Did you try this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_wlm_query_slot_count.html?

Comment: Not sure how it'll help.

Comment: by reproducible random sample you mean that if you run the same query against the same table you should receive exactly the same subset of rows?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out distribution of the unique combinations of the first N symbols in your hash dataset like this:

```
select
 substring(md5('seed' || BrowserId) from 1 for 2)
,count(1)
from PageViews pv
group by 1;
```

and then use relevant combination or multiple combinations in `WHERE` clause to filter your entries before sorting happens. For example, if you see that >100000 hashes start with 'ab' it will look like this:

```
select [columns]
from PageViews pv
where substring(md5('seed' || BrowserId) from 1 for 2)='ab'
order by md5('seed' || BrowserId)
group by BrowserId
limit 100000;
```

Also if you have many rows and you want to do sampling task frequently you could materialize hash in an additional table column once and for all so you won't have to calculate it every time.